# How to build a slide up panel that contains a RecyclerView in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, menu, overlay

I am trying to build a slide up panel that contains a RecyclerView and overlays another view, similar to the one featured in https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel, or the one used in the Lyft app:

[Lyft Sliding Panel Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhNIE.png)

I would like to be able to load the activity with the sliding panel mostly obscured, and then have the user be able to drag the sliding panel and expand it to its full height, before enabling the scrolling behavior of the RecyclerView. When the user wants to close the panel, they have to scroll to top position of the RecyclerView before the panel will start to close and return to its initial, obscured position.

The main issues I'm having trouble understanding are:

- How do I structure the layout file to get this behavior? Should I just have the RecyclerView and then programmatically change the behavior of the scroll movement to have it act like a sliding panel until it reaches the expanded position? Or should I put embed the RecyclerView in another, invisible View and then somehow have the user's touches and drags affect the invisible View first (in the manner of a sliding panel), and then re-enable the touches to affect the scrolling behavior of the RecyclerView once it's fully expanded? Or is there another, simpler way that I can do this?
- In the event that I have to direct the user touches to different UI elements, and turn scrolling / sliding behavior on / off how would I do that?

Apologies in advance if this is a bit hard to understand; I'll try my best to rephrase it if it isn't clear.